# How to trigger new custom rule context in Sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.2

I am on Sitecore `v8.2`

Here is a summary of what I have done to add the new rules.

1. Under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements` created custom actions and conditions

[Custom conditions and actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaMqy.png)

2. Then created a new rule context and new rules
   [Custom rule context and rules created underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tdyY.png)

**Custom Rule**

It checks if the item is of a certain template and if it meets my custom condition. If true, invoke my custom action.

Unfortunately, that is not getting triggered. My custom condition is not getting executed as well. Do I need to update some config to get my custom rule context to work?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not need to configure something else.

I would

1. check whether the type is referenced correctly in the rule. If not, Sitecore should show a validation warning (You can check by changing the name to a class that does not exist)
2. make sure your class has a parameterless public constructor